# Mod message lost to network glitch

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, moderator-tools, moderator-messages

The timeline:

- I started composing a moderator message on [French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/).
- At 20:53:23Z my router detected that it lost Internet connectivity. I wasn't aware of this yet.
- A few minutes later, I hit the “Notify User” button. My browser switched from https://french.stackexchange.com/users/message/create/*<NUMBER>* to https://french.stackexchange.com/users/message/save and displayed a client-side message indicating that the network couldn't be reached.
- A few minutes later, having regained network connectivity, I wanted to send the message. I tried hitting “Reload” (still on `/users/message/save`), but only got a 404 message. I then hit “Back”, but this brought me back to the message template selection screen.

The user's history shows that my message wasn't sent. There may not have been any server-side draft because my network was down. I'm bummed that there's apparently no way to recover the draft from the client side.

Please change the interface (make it less dynamic?) so that when sending a mod message sends, hitting the “Back” button brings the user back to the message sending interface, *with the latest version of the text in the edit box*.

Comment: Or just make it so the page doesn't change til after it successfully sends, so that if it breaks, you don't have to hit the back button at all, you just still have the message there? That's pretty much what happens if you post an answer without network connectivity - it just says "An error occurred submitting the answer." and leaves it as-is, unposted.

Comment: [Possibly the same root cause](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285699/moderator-message-tool-discards-my-message-if-another-moderator-simultaneously)